# Kommunikation über die regionale Sprachgrenzen

Tags: idiom, dialect, regional, oral-communication

Wenn zwei (gebildete) Personen aus zwei verschiedenen Regionen sich unterhalten oder korrespondieren, wer passt sich zu dem anderen sprachlich an? Oder geschieht dies nicht? Gibt es ungeschriebene Regel? Ich meine nicht Wörter oder Redewendungen, die dem Sprecher oder Schreiber für den Empfänger offenbar unverständlich sind, sondern Wörter, Redewendungen und grammatische Konstruktionen, die nur fremd oder komisch wirken könnte.
Sag mal ein Süddeutscher schreibt einem norddeutschen, wollte er dann z.B. „ist gestanden (gesessen/gelegen)“ oder „hat gestanden“ schreiben? Wie ist es mit dem umgekehrten Fall?
Wenn eine Anpassung geschieht, wer passt sich an?

Comment: Etwa Dänen, Schweden und Norweger sprechen normalerweise *jeweils in ihrer eigenen Sprache* miteinander und verstehen sich. Sprecher von Dialekten können das noch viel mehr praktizieren, d.h. eine Anpassung ist gar nicht strikt notwendig.

Comment: Als ich (Schwabe) im Studium zum ersten Mal Kontakt mit einer berlinernden Brandenburgerin hatte, hat eine Düsseldorferin, eine Woche lang zwischen uns hin und her übersetzt, bis wir einander einigermaßen verstanden haben. Selbst unser Hochdeutsch war durch unsere unterschiedliche Sprachmelodien nicht verständlich.

Comment: @Kilian Als Schwede kenne ich diese Tatsache sehr wohl. Es gibt jedoch homonyme Wörter die ganz verschiedene bedeutung auf den verschiedenen Sprachen haben, und die  "gebildete" leute gut als s.g "False Friends" erkennen und vermeiden, oder bewußt in gemeinsam verständliche wörter übersetzen. Wenn ich nach Dänemark oder Norwegen fahre rede ich zwar Schwedisch, verwende aber immer die im Lande gängige Wörter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vor allem in Deutschland und dort vor allem nördlich des Mains sowie besonders in größeren Städten sind Dialekte seit einigen Generationen stark auf dem Rückzug und bilden sich zu Regionalsprachen oder Mundarten zurück. Das heißt, viele Norddeutsche, Städter und Jüngere können nicht *bewusst* zwischen Dialekt und Hochsprache wechseln, für viele Süddeutsche, Österreicher und insbesondere Schweizer ist das hingegen alltäglich.

Im Laufe eines Gesprächs und erst recht eines längeren Aufenthalts in der Fremde passt man sich – außer bei großem Selbstbewusstsein, Sendungsbedürfnis, Unwissen oder Unvermögen – automatisch zumindest ein bisschen den lokalen Gepflogenheiten an. (Dies gilt bspw. auch für Fachsprachen.) In einer kleinen Gruppe kann das auch in beide Richtungen funktionieren, in größeren gilt hingegen weitgehend das Geisterfahrerprinzip, obwohl sich immer mal wieder ehemals regionale Eigenheiten überraschend schnell und nachhaltig großräumig durchsetzen. Es ist ein bisschen wie mit Lehn- und Fremdwörtern aus anderen Sprachen.

Im Gespräch mit Fremden versuchen die meisten üblicherweise, Hoch-/Schrift-/Bühnen-/Mediendeutsch zu sprechen, sind sich aber selten aller ihrer sprachlichen Eigenheiten bewusst bzw. halten sich für dialektfrei und sprechen so wie immer. Daher kann man anhand von Wortwahl, typischen Wendungen und Partikeln, Sprechmelodie oder Aussprache bei vielen die ungefähre geografische oder soziale Herkunft intuitiv heraushören – auch wenn man die Schibbolets nicht unbedingt genau benennen kann. 
Das heißt aber nicht, dass man regelmäßig andere auf die Abweichungen zur eigenen „hochdeutschen“ Sprechweise aufmerksam machen oder Änderungen erwarten würde, allerdings kann es eher unbewusst dazu führen, dass man ihre intellektuellen Fähigkeiten deswegen abwertet (was daneben etwa auch Kleidungsstil, Frisur, Geruch, Geschlecht, Hautfarbe oder Name können). Gezielt betont werden sprachliche Eigenheiten z.B. von Demagogen, Imitatoren und Karikaturisten.

Zusammengefasst: jeder versucht nach bestem Wissen und Gewissen für andere verständlich Hochdeutsch zu sprechen und darf dafür erwarten, dass eventuell verbleibende idiomatische Besonderheiten stillschweigend toleriert werden.

Answer (score 5):

Du scheinst nach regionalen Dialekten zu fragen - Hier scheint der Automatismus zu sein, dass man sich automatisch auf das Schrift-/Hochdeutsche (oder so etwas ähnliches) als kleinsten gemeinsamen Nenner einzupendeln scheint.

Genauso wie sich Menschen unterschiedlicher Sprache auf Englisch einigen können - In den Niederlanden spreche ich mit meinen Kollegen oft Englisch, einfach weil diese zwar "fremdere" und damit "weiter" als die Distanz unserer beider Muttersprachen entferntere Sprache keinen der Gesprächspartner in einen Nachteil bringt - "Englisch kann jeder".

Die Unverständlichkeit der Dialekte untereinander beruht in 95% der Fälle auf unbekannten Vokabeln oder unbekannter Aussprache. Hier nimmt man einfach ein anderes Wort, das man aus dem Fernsehen kennt und versucht, seine Aussprache etwas "gemäßigter" ans Hochdeutsche anzupassen. Danach hast du aber ausdrücklich nicht gefragt. Es bleibt allerdings nicht viel Differenz übrig, wenn man diese Unterschiede ausnimmt.

Inzwischen ist es im deutschen Sprachraum so, dass ein Großteil der Menschen seinen Dialekt verlassen und hochdeutsch reden kann - Durch die Übung aus den Medien (Fernsehen, Zeitung) *versteht* es sowieso jeder. Das war eine Generation früher nicht ganz so: Meine Mutter (geboren in den 30er Jahren) pflegte ihren starken Dialekt in einem Gespräch mit jemandem, der Hochdeutsch sprach, nicht abzulegen - Wenn sie offensichtlich nicht verstanden wurde, wiederholte sie ihren Satz vollkommen gleich - nur lauter ;)

Was die grammatischen Konstrukte angeht: Mir fällt keines ein, das zwar auf Hochdeutsch ausgesprochen möglicherweise falsch wäre, aber nicht trotzdem verstanden würde. *Dem Frieder sein Haus* versteht man auch als hochdeutsch sprechender, auch wenn es richtig *Frieders Haus* heissen müsste. Solche Konstrukte werden vom Dialekt sprechenden meistens nicht geändert, auch wenn er sich auf hochdeutsch versucht. Die Unterschiede in der Grammatik sind zwischen Hochdeutsch und den deutschen Dialekten so gesehen eher minimal.

*Den* Dialekt gibt es sowieso nicht - Von je weiter weg von der "lokalen Hauptstadt", die durch Verwaltung und Aussenbeziehung ihren Dialekt schon sehr "geglättet" hat, jemand kommt, je "exotischer" und damit weiter entfernt von der Sprache ist normalerweise sein Dialekt (Oberfränkisch vs. "Münchner bairisch" oder "Stuttgarter schwäbisch" vs. Dialekt, der in Oberschwaben gesprochen wird. An den Dialektgrenzen verschmelzen Dialekte auch miteinander z.B. der badische und der schwäbische Dialekt. Manchmal können solche Variationen bis zur Unverständlichkeit auseinanderliegen.

Hier in Süddeutschland wird übrigens das Imitieren unserer Dialekte durch jemand, der offensichtlich aus einem anderen Dialektraum kommt, oft als Affront verstanden, vor allem, wenn er es nicht richtig kann. Es ist also absolut nicht empfehlenswert, diesen Versuch zu machen. Lokale *Vokabeln* "darf" man allerdings verwenden, wenn es dem Verständnis dient.

Comment: Wir reden, soweit ich das sehe, schon von gleichwertigen Schriftsprachen. Bei fremden Sprachen hat sich natürlich Englisch als _lingua franca_ heruasgebildet, bei verschiedenen regionalen Varietäten nähme ich nur dann Rücksicht, wenn ich davon ausgehe, dass mein Gegenüber einen Ausdruck nicht kennt: à la "... Faschiertes, ihr nennt das wohl Hackfleisch ..." Eine weitere Anpassung, insb. der Grammatik findet nicht statt.

Comment: @ Ingmar, d.h. Du nimmst also an, er kenne beide Wörter nicht (Faschiertes und Hackfleisch), du aber schon? Würde der Andere zu dir dann Faschiertes sagen? Ich meine das ist worum meine Frage eigentlich geht. Darum hab ich "gebildete Leute" geschrieben

Comment: @Beta Mit seiner Erklärung haben sie ja klargestellt, dass beide jetzt beide Begriffe kennen. Damit können sie ja auch beide verwenden, ganz nach Lust und Laune. Allerdings passt man sich an, wo man ist: In München wider besseren Wissens nach einem "Brötchen" in der Bäckerei zu fragen statt nach einer "Semmel" könnte als dreist ausgelegt werden.

Comment: @Beta Eigentlich hast du Vokabeln, die "...für den Empfänger offenbar unverständlich..." sind, aus deiner Frage explizit ausgenommen

Comment: @Beta: Ich nehme an, dass er "Hackfleisch" kennt, Faschiertes aber möglicherweise nicht. Der (normalerweise) passive Wortschatz des Durchschnittsösterreichers ist diesbezüglich durch "Funk, Fernsehen & Medien" idR größer als der des durchschnittlichen Deutschen. Das ist eine Tatsache, und an sich keine besondere Leistung: da Sprache aber der Kommunikation dienen soll bietet es sich einfach an jenes Vokabular zu verwenden, das mit größter Wahrscheinlichkeit beiden bekannt ist.

Comment: Du schreibst: »Die Unterschiede in der Grammatik sind zwischen Hochdeutsch und den deutschen Dialekten so gesehen eher minimal«. Nein, das sit falsch, Die Unterschiede können erheblich sein. Der Dialekt, den ich als Kleinkind lernte (und der so gesehen eigentlich meine Muttersprache ist) kennt keinen Genitiv (»dem Vater sein Auto« kann in diesem Dialekt gar nicht anders formuliert werden), dafür aber Reste eines Duals (»griaß enk« beim Begrüßen eines Paares statt »griaß eich«) und Fragepartikel, die es im Standarddeutsch gar nicht gibt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Was "minimal" und was "erheblich" ist, ist sicher Geschmackssache. Zumindestens was die Unterschiede, die die Verständlichkeit beeinträchtigen, angeht. "Erheblich" ist für mich der Unterschied zwischen deutscher und von mir aus altbabylonischer Grammatik (nicht, dass ich den auch nur annähernd kennen würde..). Wenn du genau liest, findest du den "mein Dialekt kennt keinen Genitiv"-Fall in einem der Beispiele wieder. Dadurch wird aber die Verständlichkeit nur gering eingeschränkt - Das versteht auch ein Preuße.

Comment: Große Zustimmung zu dem, was du über das Imitieren von Dialekte schreibst. Wenn ein deutscher Comedian in Österreich auftritt und dann auf der Bühne versucht den »österreichischen Dialekt« (den es so gar nicht gibt) nachzumachen, hat er schon »*ausg'schissen*« wie man hierzulande sagen würde. Ein Amerikaner, der in Deutschland in Witzen die Deutschen mit Nazis gleichsetzt, ruft ähnliche Begeisterung hervor.

Comment: @tofro, ich würde nach einem "Brötchen" fragen, weil ich das für problemlos verständlich hielte, auch wenn ich eigentlich eine Schrippe wollte. Bei "Semmel" käme ich mir hingegen komisch vor und müsste aufpassen, nicht zu nahe in die Situation aus deinem letzten Abschnitt zu geraten. (Nicht dass ich versehentlich "a Semmeln" sage ;)